# Selecionar botão com um clique e so abrir com dois cliques

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Eu tenho um ImageButton em webform que representa diretorios em um grid usando repeater.
Como fazer para que com 1 clique apenas selecione o botão, e só abra com dois cliques?

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rtInlineBlock" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="block">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="idDirectorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("guid") %>' />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btSend" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgPath") %>' OnClick="btSend_Click" />

                                <div class="bottom">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xInfo") %>' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
 protected void btSend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var btSend = sender as ImageButton;
        var rtItem = btSend.Parent as RepeaterItem;
        var idDiretorioSelecionado = rtItem.FindControl("idDirectorio") as HiddenField;

        //faz algo

        }
```

so quero que entre nesse exemplo com duplo clique.

Dessa forma ele ja chama o evento ao clicar 1 vez, queria que ao clicar 1 vez apenas selecione e eu possa tratar isso, e com dois abrir o evento.

Comment: você pode mostrar seu code behind?

Comment: Acabei de atualizar...

Comment: Alguma solução? com js?

Comment: Eu não sou especialista em WebForms, então preciso fazer uns testes antes. Mas a primeira vista, se você estiver utilizando jQuery, pode usar o evento dblclick().

Comment: aqui ja tem o bootstrap com jquery, porem nao sei ultilizar pra essa função, se puder postar como resposta a solução ficaria melhor

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é utilizar o evento dblclick do jQuery.

Exemplo:

ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rtInlineBlock" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="block">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="idDirectorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("guid") %>' />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btSend" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgPath") %>' OnClientClick="return false;" />


            <div class="bottom">
                <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xInfo") %>' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btSend").dblclick(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/SendClick")%>',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Repare na adição do atributo ClientIDMode="Static" no ImageButton. Ele é necessário para que possamos selecionar o elemento via jQuery com $("#btSend"). Além disso, é necessário retirar o evento OnClick original e incluir a propriedade OnClientClick="return false;" para evitar que ocorra PostBack na página ao clicar no botão.

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendClick()
{
    //faz algo
}
```

Estamos fazendo o uso de um WebMethod para ser chamado via AJAX no cliente. Repare que o método precisa ser estático e estar decorado com o atributo [WebMethod]. No meu exemplo a função está como void, mas você pode retornar qualquer tipo, inclusive tipos complexos. O framework se encarrega da serialização pra JSON.

Observação: para que uma chamada pra um WebMethod funcione em uma aplicação WebForms, é necessário alterar a seguinte configuração no arquivo **~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs**:

De:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Para:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

Sem isso, a requisição AJAX recebe um retorno **401 (unauthorized)**.

Espero ter te ajudado.